# Syntax Error Bareword found running Perl from Ubuntu Shell using variables containing forward slashes

Tags: perl, bash, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu Natty.

I'm trying to edit a text file using command-line perl. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
path_to_php_exec="/usr/local/php/bin/php"
path_to_php_prog="/root/run/php_gearman_worker.php"
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/(command[ ]*=[ ]*)[^\n]+/\${1}=$path_to_php_exec $path_to_php_prog\n/g" /etc/supervisord_program_gearman.conf
```

However, when I run this I get the following error

```
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/(command[ ]*=[ ]*)[^\n]+/${1}=/usr"
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "php\"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/(command[ ]*=[ ]*)[^\n]+/${1}=/usr"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the forward slashes in my shell variables but I'm not quite sure. Still somewhat of a newbie with command line scripting.

I would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly it. You can choose different delimiters for Perl's `s///` command. Also, your regex is line oriented, so why not parse the file line-by-line?

```
perl -i -pe \
    "$(printf 's{(command\s*=\s*).*}{$1 %s %s}g' "$path_to_php_exec" "$path_to_php_prog")" \
    /etc/supervisord_program_gearman.conf
```

I assume you don't want to double the equal sign in the output file, so I removed it from the substitution block.

Comment: Thanks Glenn #lifesaver. I'm a little lost with the syntax but I'll do my best to extrapolate when I need to use this method in another context. Cheers.